# Como definir dinamicamente a função a ser chamada em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, funções, variáveis

Olá, gostaria que o usuário do programa escrevesse uma função para posterior utilização, porém estou com dificuldade para implementar isso:

Vide o exemplo abaixo:

```
def funcao_integracao(x):
    y=x**2
    return y

def trapezio():
    intervalo = []
    val = 0

    intervalo.append(float(input("Digite o intervalo inferior de integração: ")))
    print(' ')
    intervalo.append(float(input("Digite o intervalo superior de integração: ")))
    print("Digite o número de iterações: ")

    it = int(input("=>"))
    h = (intervalo[1] - intervalo[0])/it
    for i in range(it):
        val += h/2*(funcao_integracao(intervalo[0]+(h*i))+funcao_integracao(intervalo[0]+(h*(i+1))))
    print("A integração da função no intervalo {} até {} com {} iterações é: " .format(intervalo[0], intervalo[1], it), val)
```

Em `funcao_integracao(x)`, ao invés do programa usar uma função pré estipulada `(x**2)`, gostaria que o usuário informasse a função que ele desejar.

EDITADO POR **de_python**

Uma alternativa seria usar a função

```
def funcao(func, x):
    if 'x' in func:
        func = func.replace('x','{x}')
    func = func.format(x=x)
    return eval(func)
```

Você consegue escolher qual a conta que irá na primeira posição, por exemplo:

```
funcao("10**x", 2)
```

Em que o retorno é

```
100
```

Comment: Não entendi. Você quer que o usuário escolha entre funções que você definiu ou se quer que o usuário escreva a sua própria função?

Comment: Gostaria que o usuário escreva a própria função

Comment: A pergunta está clara para mim. Só o título que não estava muito bom. Sugeri umas edições para deixar tudo mais alinhado.

Comment: Você pode utilizar o f-string para criar um texto dinâmico, onde o 'x' da função fosse o texto da conta que ele deseja.

A exemplo

def funcao(func, x):
    if 'x' in func:
        func = func.replace('x','{x}')
    func = func.format(x=x)
    return eval(func)

funcao("10**x", 2)

==> 100

Comment: Não concordei com o fechamento da pergunta. Para mim ela está clara e eu tenho uma boa resposta para dar, ainda mais com as recentes edições.